# How to get a better answer for an already answered question?

Tags: support

Suppose I put up a question in Ask Ubuntu. Now somebody posted an answer. But that answer seems difficult to be carried out for me. That doesn't mean that the answer provided is wrong. So, now I want a more easier and better answer. What can I do other than just waiting for someone to post a better answer? Maybe I can put up a bounty but anyone who sees the bountied question with an answer that has the potential to work right might not try to give a better answer. So there is every chance of my bounty being wasted(I maybe wrong on this but I dunno if the bounty would come back to me if its purpose is unsolved as I have never placed a bounty before). What do you suggest I do in this situation?

Comment: You can try asking the person who answered for more clarifications in a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get to add a message to the bounty when you add it, explaining what exactly you need:

[image]

There are also several different bounty reasons to pick from.

Bounties never come back to you, unless a moderator refunds them for moderation purposes (i.e. to close the question, etc).